# adding sub menu in customer account dashboard navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, menu, navigation, submenu

Is it Possible to add a sub menu in customer account dashboard?
Example:

```
ACCOUNT DASHBOARD
ACCOUNT INFORMATION
...
...
...
CUSTOM LINK
    -sub menu 1
    -sub menu 2
    -sub menu 3
```

Could anybody help me on this?

navigation.phtml

```
 <ul>
        <?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
        <?php $_index = 1; ?>
        <?php $_count = count($_links); ?>
        <?php foreach ($_links as $_link): ?>
            <?php $_last = ($_index++ >= $_count); ?>
            <?php if ($this->isActive($_link)): ?>
                <li class="current<?php echo ($_last ? ' last' : '') ?>"><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><strong><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></strong></a><ul><li>aaaa</li></ul></li>
            <?php else: ?>
                <li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><ul><li>aaaa</li></ul></li>
                <li<?php echo ($_last ? ' class="last"' : '') ?>><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><ul><li>aaaa</li></ul></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Not possible in default magento.Need some customization in file default\template\customer\account\navigation.phtml

Comment: what sort of customization ? cause I tried there to put nested list but  it didn't work

Comment: can you share your code